# C# updating textbox text from another textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to make a program where, there is blank text in textbox 2, you type text from textbox 1 it updates and goes into textbox 2

so basically, textbox 1 is empty, whatever typed in textbox1 updates and goes into textbox 2

View the images below to understand what I mean.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2djK6.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kpAx.png

Comment: You need to handle `void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` event.

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I tried one thing, I don't know what to type :(

Comment: It's nice that you want to do that. But what is your question? We do not write your program, you have to do that yourself. But you can receive help here if you have a specific problem with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `((TextBox)sender).Text;`. Try this:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     textBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
}
```

**UPDATE**: Responding to your newest comment, here's how you can replace the field values on Enter.

If you want to do a `String.Replace` when the user hits enter, then go to your TextBox events, look for `KeyUp`, and add this code:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            this.textBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Replace("whatever", "something else");
        }
    }
```

Comment: One more thing, Now that that is out of the way, How can I replace a stirng inside the textbox? I know the textbox1.text.replace("", ""); way, But I need it to happen when they hit enter on the textbox

Comment: I need it so, whatever is typed into textbox, whatever the user types, replaces string in another.

Comment: `this.textBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text.Replace("whatever", "something else");`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood well you want changes in `TextBox 1` goes autmatically to `TextBox 2`. So you can use related events to do this. If you are in `WinForms` click on the `TextBox 1` control then take a look at properties/event. It is possible to define a proper event there. In the event handler you must get text from `TextBox 1` and update `TextBox 2` based on it.

**Update 1**
See sample code:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
}
```

**Update 2**
Steps to create the application:

1. Crate a new WinForms project by `Visual Studio`.
2. Add 2 `TextBox` to the form. Make sure names are `textBox1` and `textBox2`
3. Click on the `TextBox1`. Then in the properties window click on the `Events` tab.
4. Scroll down until you see `TextChanged` event. Double click on cell next to it. It will opens code for you with an empty method.
5. Insert `textBox2.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;` into body of this method.
6. You are done. Now run the application and see what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for answering but looking for a better example.

Comment: It Is not working, It doesn't update the text in textbox unfortunantly :(

Comment: Why are you using `((TextBox)sender).Text;`? You just need `textBox2.Text = textBox1.Text`.

Comment: Using `sender` give the ability to no knowing name of `textBox2`.